# Keyboard stops working randomly and sometimes a circle with line through it keeps popping up

Tags: keyboard, cinnamon

I'm using Ubuntu Cinnamon. A problem that I'm currently facing is that the keyboard keeps stops working randomly. I went through several troubleshooting processes, but in vain. I checked whether it's a hardware issue or software. I checked in Windows, but it's working fine there. I checked with a live ISO, and the problem persists there. Even after a fresh installation of Ubuntu Cinnamon the problem persists. Then I moved to Linux Mint, and still the problem persists. Sometimes a circle with a line through it (a prohibited symbol) appears like the below image.

[image]